# MSB8008: Specified platform toolset <v120> is not installed or invalid error without installing VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, dll, msbuild

I am trying to build the C++ dlls with Msbuild from command prompt. But it was throwing the error as:

> MS8008: Specified platform toolset  is not installed or invalid.

I could see in some answers its been mentioned as issue will be resolved if VS2013 is installed in the machines, but Im trying to run in a build server where we shouldn't install visual studio. I have installed Microsoft Build Tools 2013 and 2015 even then the issue is resolved. Please help me if any configuration changes required or any other software's needs to be installed to build C++ dll with msbuild.